# Issues with minimize/restore toggle for Gui via Hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm working on a Gui based tool for my workspace to provide simple text pasting & WinMinimize/WinRestore functionality. The issue I am facing is with the minimize/restore toggle function.

the current code I am using is detailed below:

```
;                               Functions
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
GuiToggle()
{
    Sleep, 50
    if WinActive("ServiceDeskAssist")
    {
        Gui, -AlwaysOnTop
        WinMinimize, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinWaitNotActive, ServiceDeskAssist
    }
    else
    {
        WinRestore, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinActivate, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinWaitActive, ServiceDeskAssist
        Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
    }
Sleep, 50
}

;                                Hotkeys
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
^z::GuiToggle()
```

The idea is for the toggle to minimize/restore depending on the Gui's current state, however if the Gui is present but still visible (i.e. +AlwaysOnTop) it's not "Active" so it will be restored instead of minimized.
Is there any way to correct the functionality of this?

Comment: Hello Daniel, your question is a bit confusing, please try clarify/simplify it. Which method are you using now? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems WinGet - MinMax was the way forward.
The following code is working without a hitch:

```
;                               Functions
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
GuiToggle()
{
    Sleep, 50
    WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ServiceDeskAssist
    If(WinState==0||WinState==1)
    {
        Gui, -AlwaysOnTop
        WinMinimize, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinWaitNotActive, ServiceDeskAssist
    }
    else if(WinState==-1)
    {
        WinRestore, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinActivate, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinWaitActive, ServiceDeskAssist
        Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
    }
Sleep, 50
}

Toggle(a)
{
    Sleep, 50
    WinGet, WinState, MinMax, % a
    If(WinState==0||WinState==1)
    {
        WinMinimize, % a
        WinWaitNotActive, % a
    }
    else if(WinState==-1)
    {
        WinRestore, % a
        WinActivate, % a
        WinWaitActive, % a
    }
Sleep, 50
}

;                                Hotkeys
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{

^x::ExitApp

^z::GuiToggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless `ServiceDeskAssist` is a super-global variable, then `if WinActive(ServiceDeskAssist)` is wrong.
`WinMinimize, ServiceDeskAssist` is using `ServiceDeskAssist` as a literal, not a string (Which is what I think you intended to do for the IF statement)
`WinRestore` does not automatically activate

```
;                               Functions
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
GuiToggle()
{
    Sleep, 50
    if WinActive("ServiceDeskAssist")
    {
        Gui, -AlwaysOnTop
        WinMinimize, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinWaitNotActive, ServiceDeskAssist
    }
    else
    {
        WinRestore, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinActivate, ServiceDeskAssist
        WinWaitActive, ServiceDeskAssist
        Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
    }
    Sleep, 50
}
;                                Hotkeys
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
^z::GuiToggle()
```

Also, why not pass in the title of the window to the function? That way it becomes re-usable

```
;                               Functions
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
GuiToggle(winTitle)
{
    Sleep, 50
    if WinActive(winTitle)
    {
        Gui, -AlwaysOnTop
        WinMinimize, % winTitle
        WinWaitNotActive, % winTitle
    }
    else
    {
        WinRestore, % winTitle
        WinActivate, % winTitle
        WinWaitActive, % winTitle
        Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
    }
    Sleep, 50
}
;                                Hotkeys
; }-----------------------------------------------------------------------{
^z::GuiToggle("ahk_class Notepad")
```

Comment: Hi @Clive in this instance, I'm just looking for the hotkey to reliably minimize and restore the Gui. WinActivate & clearly using a variable rather than a literal appears to be the main two things I was missing, however I guess the method still isn't behaving in the way I would like it to.

Comment: I've updated the original post to detail the progress made thanks to your advice